# Getting duplicates entries while inserting data in titandb

Tags: scala, titan

Below is the Scala code that I am using to insert the data into titan.

```
for(n <- nodes){
   stringNodes = stringNodes.concat("v"+n.letter+" = graph.addVertex('"+n.label+"');") 
   for(a <- n.attributes){
     stringNodes = stringNodes.concat("v"+n.letter+".property('"+a.name+"','"+row(row.fieldIndex(a.name))+"');") 
   }
 }
```

The challenge we are facing is every time we are getting multiple entries of the one node. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ7wN.png

Can you please help and advise the best way to insert unique records in titan db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of how you would do this in Scala but a good way of ensuring vertices are unique according to some property is to index that property to be unique.

As outlined [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html) you could create a property on your vertex `myId` and tell the schema that it is unique. That way you can do quick lookups by that id and more importantly let Titan ensure that the vertex is unique by that property. For example:

```
//Open up managment interface
graph = TitanFactory.open(config);
mgmt = graph.openManagement();

//Create the property key
propKey = management.makePropertyKey("myId").dataType(String.class)).make();

//Tell Titan it should be unique
mgmt.buildIndex("byMyIdUnique", Vertex.class).addKey(propKey).unique().buildCompositeIndex();
mgmt.commit();
```

The above code will tell Titan that you have a property called `myId` which should be unique. That way if you ever do the following:

```
graph.addVertex().property("myId", 1); 
graph.addVertex().property("myId", 1);
```

Titan will fail and warn you of the duplicates.